# Logstash Grok filter mysql slow-queries

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm try to use grok to filter mysql slow-queries. And i'm need to get

- database name
- User
- IP
- Query_time
- Command

Somebody help me?

```
# User@Host: tysa6775_ua_data[tysa6775_ua_data] @ localhost []  Id:   360
# Query_time: 1.627188  Lock_time: 0.000246 Rows_sent: 5566  Rows_examined: 459414
use tysa6775_au_data1;
SET timestamp=1541421036;
select * from table_rating where id_product=1009 order by ngaytao desc;
# User@Host: tysa6775_ua_data[tysa6775_ua_data] @ localhost []  Id:   360
# Query_time: 0.000569  Lock_time: 0.000308 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 3
SET timestamp=1541421036;
select * from table_hoidap where id_product=1009 order by ngaytao desc;
# User@Host: tysa6775_ua_data[tysa6775_ua_data] @ localhost []  Id:   360
# Query_time: 0.000349  Lock_time: 0.000208 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 28
SET timestamp=1541421036;
select * from table_product_like where id_product='1009' and ip_nguoilike='5.188.210.8' order by stt,id desc;
```

Comment: Please post text results of SHOW TABLE CREATE table_rating;  for suggestions to reduce Rows_examined in the first query.  To log slow queries, you may wish to use the following in my.cnf/my.ini [mysqld] section, A) log_queries_not_using_indexes=OFF  B) long_query_time=1  C) slow_query_log_file=slow-query.log  D) min_examined_row_limit=1

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow mate. It would be nice if you post an example of what you have tried already, to see where you are failing and being able to help you. Also, from where is supposed grok to get the IP if it is not there? Do you mean the host? Try to improve your post and the community will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you're trying to access is spread out over multiple lines in the log file, you need to use the [multiline codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html), which will make a single event from those lines.